# AngularJS form sending wrong values

Tags: angularjs

I have a form and this is the code for on of the input fields:

```
 <input type="text" name="user[job]" ng-model="updateAccountForm.user.job" ng-init="updateAccountForm.user.job = '{{user.job}}'" value="{{user.job}}" />
```

The value is showing correctly. The problem is the following: If I edit the field the value is sent correctly in the PUT request. If I do not edit the form field then the value that is sent is literally `{{user.job}}`

What could be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are doing it wrong, you have to do something like this:

```
 <input type="text" name="user[job]" ng-model="updateAccountForm.user.job" ng-init="updateAccountForm.user.job=user.job" />
```

I suggest you to avoid this initialization, why you don't put your logic into the controller?

Comment: Thanks! That works, although it doesn't set the initial value in the form field.

Comment: Not as intended :p This is an edit form and it's supposed to show the current values of the user(job, etc) in the input fields. That is working correctly. The problem is that when I do not submit the form fields the values that is sent to the server is {{user.job}}, literally.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain you that value="{{user.job}}" can be omitted. You are using ng-model to set the default property value

Comment: It's solved. The problem is that user.job is only set when an async function ends running. I had to call $watch and update $scope.updateAccountForm.user.job there. Anyway, I'll accept your answer because you pointed me in the right direction :)